# Prefixing my URL with http:// causes my site not to load

Tags: apache, http, web, https

I'm encountering a weird issue accessing my site. If I type in http:// in front of the URL then the site doesn't load, however if i don't include the http:// the site loads fine. I think it may be an error with how my DNS is set up but if so then I am unsure what records to modify/add in order to fix it. The site is running on a linux (Ubuntu 12.04) server with apache.

Ok So further testing yields that `http://www.example.com/` works but when I don't include the www (`http://example.com/`) it doesn't resolve. Any ideas on why discluding the `www.` would break it?

Comment: If the hostname is resolving then it's not the DNS's fault. http:// just means use the http:// protocol on port 80. What happens if you type www.yoururl.com:80? If you have an ssl certificate installed then it might be https

Comment: Thanks for the answer. adding port 80 to the end doesn't change anything, www.myurl.com:80 still resolves. Could it be an error in my apache configuration?

Comment: If :80 works but http:// doesn't then it sounds like a client issue. Have you tried another browser?

Comment: Yes I have, and I've had my coworkers try it as well. We're all stumped.

Comment: just copy the url from the browser, and paste into some where else like notepad. what would you get?

Comment: What do you mean @DRAJI? `www.example.com` loads, whereas `http://example.com` does not load. When I type in `http://example.com` my browser (and other browsers) just translates it to `example.com`

Comment: I mean, when you copy url from location bar(when enter http://example.com), what it would be return? (just check it by paste in to notepad)

Comment: I mean, when you copy url from location bar(when enter www.example.com), what it would be return? (just check it by paste in to notepad)

Comment: Show us your vhost-Config